# UPDATE table 1 to NULL when value is not null in table 2 in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to copy number from Table1.cardNumber to Table2.cardNumber. After this step I am going to delete value from Table1.cardNumber. I want to be sure that cleaning value from Table1 happen only when value in Table2 is not empty. All of this I Invoke-Sqlcmd with Powershell

When i try to do

```
UPDATE table1
    SET cardNumber = Null
    FROM table1
    WHERE table1.AccountName = '$($table1AccountName'
    AND table2.cardNumber IS NOT NULL
```

I get an error

> Multi-part identifier table2 could not be bound.

How I can check if other row is not empty and then Update table1?

Comment: Hint:  `FROM table2`.  I'm voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Your advice is correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

May be you need something like

```
 UPDATE T SET T.CARDNUMBER=NULL
 FROM TABLE1 AS T
 JOIN TABLE2 AS T2 ON T.AccountName =T2.AccountName 
 WHERE T2.CARDNUMBER IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I will use this in other case in my script. Thank you